# No sound on ubuntu 22.10 after switching from x.org x server to nvidia-driver-525

Tags: nvidia, sound, 22.10

Yesterday, I switched from nVidia driver 515 to 525 and shutdown my PC later. After I booted this morning, the driver changed from 525 to X Server and caused some graphics issues, I managed to solve by switching to nVidia again.

Now the actual problem: after switching to the nVidia-driver-525 again, I have no sound. The output option in sound options only show "Dummy Output", but no actual sound device.

When I run `aplay --list-devices`, it returns this:

```
aplay: device_list:274: no sound cards detected
```

`pacmd` works fine. `lspci` returns this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4650 (rev 05)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 05)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH Shared SRAM (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH HECI Controller #1 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a86 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SPI Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V (rev 11)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

my current kernel version is this: `5.19.0-28-generic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem: Ubuntu didn't have the modules needed to recognize the sound card, so you need to install those. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) website tells you how.